Vibrating liquid
I'm trying to re-create this scene:

From the following showreel between seconds 12 and 14. https://youtu.be/W37A0YmkXTc?si=Nt8fJqB4K2mgIDts
In real life this looks like what happens when there is a vibrating object just underneath the surface of a liquid. I've tried simulating this,I've tried recreating it with geo-nodes, nothing comes close. I know it was not done in blender, but surely it must be possible.
Any help is much appreciated, or even just pointing me in the right direction.

It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.
